# Maven can't locate JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, maven

I installed maven and added it to the path in my user variable but when i ran maven -v command from my command prompt, it showed that "maven is not recognized as an internal or external command ... ". When i run SET JAVA_HOME command it shows that the path to my jdk is okay. Before installing maven i deleted my old jdk 1.8.0 and installed jdk 1.8.0_201, whenever i start my netbeans IDE now it brings up a dialog box showing "Cannot locate java installation in the specified jdkhome: C\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.8.0 Do you want to try to use default version?" When i click yes, my netbeans IDE works perfectly. I think the issue with the maven and jdk are related, i am using windows 8.1 OS. Can anyone please tell me how to get maven working? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: try "mvn -v"...

Comment: i tried "mvn -v" and got the same result.

Comment: Is it a typo or does your jdkhome miss a colon? `C\Program Files...` instead of `C:\Program Files...`?

Comment: this is my JAVA_HOME path - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201 Is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call Maven with `mvn`. If calling `mvn -v` does not work, `mvn` is probably not on your path. Make sure that the bin directory in your Maven installation is on your Windows PATH.

Comment: maven is in my windows system variable path * C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Password Manager\;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201;C:\Users\Babatunde\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.0 but it still not working

Comment: Perhaps it is supposed to have "/bin" after "apache-maven-3.6.0" in your path variable. The directory spec in the path has to be the directory that contains the executable. On my machine, that's a 'bin' directory below the maven installation directory

Comment: IT HAS WORKED!!!!! Maven is working on my machine, thank you so much, thank you.I added maven's path ending with \bin and it is working. I checked it with mvn -v command, it is working. @Arcy, thanks a lot.

Comment: Am glad it is working for you. Please be sure to upvote any answers you find useful, and mark one as the answer if you think it was the best answer to your question. That's how StackOverflow rolls...

Comment: Oh - triangles to the left of each answer, those are for up/down voting. And for questions you have asked, there is a radio button on every answer; clicking on one of those will indicate that you have 'accepted' that answer. It gives points to people who are helpful and who answer questions correctly, which builds reputation, etc. In this case, @JF Meier wrote this answer and I've only commented on it, so marking it would give him the answer credit; upvoting gives him a little more credit (since it was useful). You can also upvote comments, though that may require some rep of your own.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, i have up vote @JF's answer although I can't up vote comments for now. Thanks a billion.

Comment: @JF, i did, it showed 1 and it change back to 0. What should i do?

Comment: I think you need 15 reputation to upvote at all, not just comments. Sorry, didn't realize that when I suggested it. I'll upvote the answer myself.